# Zoom API : account does not enabled REST API

Tags: jwt, zoom-sdk

I am trying to call the zoom API using the JWT token but it returns:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "Account does not enabled REST API."
}
```

The query I am using is:

```
POST https://api.zoom.us/v2/users

Headers:
  Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

How do I enable the REST APIs for my zoom account?

Comment: I'm encountering the same error, although it was functioning properly previously. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed in this situation?
 {"code":200,"message":"Account does not enabled REST API."}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using free account api will not support as paid plan needed. If you have tried Developer api then in that case your trial api will be expired.

Answer (score 0):

JWT authentication got deprecated and you now have to use oAuth, please follow the instructions here:
https://developers.zoom.us/docs/internal-apps/

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, and it was related to the token. The token is no longer created using JWT.

Here is the code I used to create the token:

```
        $account_id = (your account id);
        $secret_key = (your secret key);
        $client_id = (your client id);
        
        $base64Encoded = base64_encode($client_id:$secret_key");
    
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://zoom.us/oauth/token",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  "account_id=$account_id&grant_type=account_credentials",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "authorization: Basic $base64Encoded",
                "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

To be able to use Zoom REST APIs successfully, please ensure you have below:

1. A paid zoom account.
2. The user by which you call APIs should be Active.
3. An active Zoom account (A Zoom account can have multiple users in it).

Follow the [official documentation](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/using-zoom-apis/) for further information.